# Update Excel object embedded in Word document when opened

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I have an Excel sheet embedded in a Word document, this object was created from Word and no xlsx file exist for it.

There is only one cell and it has a random number formula that returns a new number each time the document is opened when used in Excel, but does not refresh on Word until I open the embedded object.

Desired behavior would be to refresh when Word document is opened without editing the embedded object.

"Update automatic links at open" is already enabled, the object is not a link.

Comment: In Word menu *File > Options > Advanced*, section *General* (at the end), do you have checked "Update automatic links at open"?

Comment: The embedded object is not a link. This option is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible - the object needs to be activated in order for it to "be" an Excel object. As far as Word is concerned, an embedded object is like a picture (programmatically a `Shape` or an `InlineShape`). Only once it's activated does it have access to its "OLE Server" (the thing that tells it how to behave) - Excel, in this case.

It would be possible to use macro code, an macro named `AutoOpen` for example, to trigger this.